# Javascript clear array was working but suddenly it's not

Tags: javascript, cordova

Iam working in cordova with cordova-local-notifications plugin. First the clear function was working but now when I clear and restart the application the notification all show up...

This is my clear function:

```
    $('.clearbtn').click(function(){
        var arraylength = info.data;
        arraylength.splice(0,arraylength.length);
        console.log('clear',arraylength);
    });
```

The console log shows me that the array has nothing inside it. And this is the outcome of the `console.log(info.data)`

[image]

and this is the all reminder page:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#all",function(){
        var html = '';

        for(var count = 0; count < info.data.length; count++){
            console.log(info.data);
            var time = new Date(info.data[count][3]);

            var addHour = time.setHours(time.getHours());
            var date = new Date(addHour);
            // Hours part from the timestamp
            var hours = date.getHours();
            // Minutes part from the timestamp
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
            // Will display time in 10:30:23 format
            var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);

            var imgPath = 'img/icons/alert.png';

            html = html + "<tr><td class='img-table'><img src=" + imgPath + "></td>" + "<td><span class='time-aside'><strong>" + formattedTime + "</strong></span><h4>" + info.data[count][1] + "</h4><p>" + info.data[count][2] + "</p></td></tr>";
        } 

        $('.clearbtn').click(function(){
            var arraylength = info.data;
            arraylength.splice(0,arraylength.length);
            console.log('clear',arraylength);
        });

        $("table#notificationTable tbody").empty();
        $("table#notificationTable tbody").append(html).closest("table#notificationTable").table("refresh").trigger("create");  
    });
```

I really don't get it because it was working before but I don't know why its not anymore!

Comment: What is the expected outcome ? You are doing splice over the entire array so it will work on the array in place and will remove all the elements as you are working over the whole length

Comment: [Too much irrelevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Vatsal The expected outcome is that I clear all the notifications out of the array when I reopen the app there are no notifications shown there.

Comment: After  arraylength.splice(0,arraylength.length) array is blank. What is the issue? Moreover just to clear the array you can just fdo array.length = 0 or array = [].

Comment: @Vatsal I tried that too but when I reopen the app it will show everything again..

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Vatsal how do I do that with that plugin?

Comment: can you create an example  in jsfiddle.net where this issue can be replicated

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7wvwsy8b/1/ this is an created fiddle and also edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to clear localStorage aswell.. Because I push it to localstorage as string. Here is a rewrite of the function:

```
    $('.clearbtn').click(function(){
        var arraylength = info.data;
        arraylength = 0;
        localStorage.clear();
    });
```